# Seg fault when using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: fedora, installation, pdf

I'm using wkhtmltopdf through the command line. It successfully creates a PDF given a URL but is very slow and the output ends with a seg fault. Any idea how to resolve this? How can I verify that I successfully installed wkhtmltopdf?

The command I am running:

```
wkhtmltopdf MYURL test.pdf
```

I verified that the following dependencies are installed:

```
libXrender-devel-0.9.5-1.fc12.x86_64
libXrender-0.9.5-1.fc12.x86_64
xorg-x11-utils-7.4-7.fc12.x86_64
openssl-1.0.0b-1.fc12.1.x86_64
```

Here is the output from the command:

```
Loading pages (1/5)
Resolving links (2/5)                                              
Counting pages (3/5)                                                      
Printing pages (5/5)                                                      
Done                                                                      
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

*Some* websites work perfectly fine while others, including every URL I need this functionality to work with, encounter the above error. Is there something about my files in particular that are causing the seg fault? They're all coded in very basic HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that *any* time you get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` it is because of an error in the program. *No* program should dump core for any reason. Core is dumped so that an application can be debugged using the resulting core file.

Comment: While an application should not cause a core dump, few segfaults actually result in a core dump. A core dump is normally indicative of a fault in the kernel.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers: You are confusing an application's memory dump (or "core" dump) with a dump of kernel memory (_also_ called a "core dump"). Both exist. It can be trivial to write a program that dumps core. You may be able to see more from core(5). In my version of that man page, the first line is: _"The default of certain signals is to cause a process to terminate and produce a core dump file, a disk file containing an image of the process's memory at the time of termination."_

Comment: if that is correct then I stand corrected and whoever wrote that man page should learn that a memory dump is not a core dump.